# python - remove line breaks when importing csv

Tags: python

I am trying to import some data from a csv. However, for some reason I have some line breaks at the beginning of some of my data. I am using this code to import:

```
import csv

def opencsv():
    with open('static/urls.csv', encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as csvfile:
        lines = csv.reader(csvfile, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        for row in lines:
            csvrows = ''.join(row)
```

It all works fine until there is a line break (I am talking about line break like this '\n' and not a blank space) in the data that I try to import.

Whenever there is a line break my csvrows will looke like this

```
cvsrows = '"'
```

ignoring all the other characters that were initially in the cell of the csv. Any idea how I can get rid of the linebreak when importing?

Comment: Can you show us a toy example of your file?

Comment: the csv file looks like this when importing
row1: "Apple"
row2: "/n"+"Lemon"
row3: "Orange"

Comment: how can it be `'"'` if it is newline character?

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
        import pandas as pd
        df=pd.read_csv(filename).dropna().reset_index().drop(['index'], axis=1)
```

Also please share a sample of your file as it helps us in recreating the issue and solving it.

Comment: if possible I would prefer not to use pandas since this creates me some troubles on AWS EB

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `csvrows = ''.join(row)` with `csvrows = ''.join(row.strip())`